# Spring-boot not creating graphql endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I want to integrate Graphql in my project. I started with a new Spring boot project following (several) tutorial but none of them are working: the graphql endpoint does not appear, it seems that the graphqls file is not detected?

My project is a Maven project with following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>5.10.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

To keep the post brief, I tried to put only the relevant dependencies avoiding the others (Lombok, jpa, etc...)

And my graphqls file (in resources folder):

```
type Vehicle {
    id: ID!,
    type: String,
    modelCode: String,
    brandName: String,
    launchDate: String
}
type Query {
    vehicles(count: Int):[Vehicle]
    vehicle(id: ID):Vehicle
}
type Mutation {
    createVehicle(type: String!, modelCode: String!, brandName: String, launchDate: String):Vehicle
}
```

According to the documentation, the graphql endpoint should be created since I have a graphql-spring-boot-starter dependency and a schema which will be created automatically with my vehicle.graphqls file (and the graphql-java-tools dependency)

> The servlet becomes accessible at /graphql if graphql-spring-boot-starter added as a dependency to a boot application and a GraphQLSchema bean is present in the application  [...]
>   A GraphQL schema can also be automatically created when a supported graphql-java schema library is found on the classpath.

The only way I made the graphql endpoint appearing is by creating a schema programmatically (which I want to avoid):

```java
@Bean
    GraphQLSchema schema() {
    return GraphQLSchema.newSchema()
            .query(GraphQLObjectType.newObject()
                    .name("query")
                    .field(field -> field
                            .name("test")
                            .type(Scalars.GraphQLString)
                            .dataFetcher(environment -> "response")
                            )
                    .build())
            .build();
}
```

I guess that I missed something but after one day of attempts, I am now stuck, I don't see what can be my mistake.

Comment: You don't need to build the schema (completely) manually, but you do need to build it. Since you have the schema defined, you just need to use it to build the endpoints. See [this tutorial](https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/) for more details.

Comment: I don't really see the difference beetween what I do and the tutorial you mentioned, the principle remains the same. A schema is defined in a json file and classes (`GraphQLResolver` in my case) are implemented for searching. But since I use the `com.graphql-java-kickstart.graphql-java-tool`, I should not have to write this GraphQLProvider as with `com.graphql-java.graphql-java`. But I may have miss your point?

Comment: Well if the `kickstart` package is supposed to handle that for you, I suppose not.

Comment: try setting this property: `graphql.servlet.enabled=true`

Comment: Me too facing the same problem .... are you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Sorry but I restarted with a working project I updated, I was unable to find why my 1st project was not working as expected

Comment: I have been trying to make this thing work for a while, had same problem because I was trying to define both beans & java-graphql way.  When you are stuck,  I'd suggest to look into project dependencies and code given on github, as many of starter projects in that repo is for example purposes. The java-graphql-tools will pickup your .graphqls files from resource folder and create servlet with spring beans automatically. The bad thing is there are too many possibilities to do same thing with this kickstarter i.e. beans,components, schema files, autowiring resolvers with schema etc.

Answer (score -2):

Are you exposing `GraphQLQueryResolver` as a `@Bean` so that the autoconfig knows to search for your schema files?

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class GraphQLConfiguration {

    @Bean
    QueryResolver queryResolver() {
        return new QueryResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    MutationResolver mutationMutation() {
        return new MutationResolver();
    }

}
```

[Documentation for author's quote](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot#enable-graphql-servlet)

> The servlet becomes accessible at /graphql if graphql-spring-boot-starter added as a dependency to a boot application and a GraphQLSchema bean is present in the application. Check out the simple example for the bare minimum required.

> *A GraphQL schema can also be automatically created when a supported graphql-java schema library is found on the classpath.*

Following THAT thread of documentation will eventually lead you [the GraphQL Java Tools project documentation](https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/tools/) which explains how to generate the necessary `GraphQLSchema` object from your `.graphqls` definitions. Lastly, we have to map those definitions into Java somehow, and this is Spring Boot so `@Bean` your root resolver(s) so it has an implementation to work with and you should be good to go.

Comment: Where does `QueryResolver` and `MutationResolver` come from? I'm not able to find these objects in the GraphQL java library